# Is it possible to send data to phpmyadmin from a windows/android application on a phone?

Tags: php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am developing an application that needs to send data to a server so that the server data can be outputted on a website table.

My question is how is it done? I already know how to create tables and whatnot, but when a user creates an account on the phone application, how is it going to appear on the table on phpmyadmin?

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a database administration application. If you put the data into your database correctly, then it will display correctly in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I want to know how can data from an android phone or windows phone can be sent to the tables in phpmyadmin

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding what phpmyadmin is. What you should be asking is how to send data to the underlying database, and that's an extremely broad question as there could be any number of ways to do that.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example of a method to send data to the aforementioned database? I could start with that idea if you may share  anything.

Answer (score 1):

@ Zarathuztra convenient [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is a tool to manage MySQL databases. 
What you need is a script on the server that receives the requests from the smartphone is making special thinks inside. Save or manipulates the data in the database and sends the result back on to the phone. This is not the opinion, we can teach you on StackOverflow, sorry.

Watch out for cloud database services to your problem on the internet or ask are PHP-coder for help.